# How to use django_socketio on a django project

Tags: python, django, websocket, real-time, django-socketio

I'd like to use real-time application on my website on django, I installed django_socketio, but I don't found a tutorial witch talk about how can I use it. Have you an idea how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://jpadilla.com/post/74391616727/the-easiest-way-to-add-websockets-to-django) might be a good place to start. It's not exactly socketio but it's a great place to start.

Here is the [demo](http://dwr-example.herokuapp.com/).